# Request mapping for CSS

Tags: spring-mvc

I have controller that should manage all requests on server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", produces = {"text/plain", "application/*"})
@Controller
public class HomeController {
...
}
```

Also I have mapping for resources in xml:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/assets/**"/>
```

Homecontroller intercept all requests to server (include to /assets/** mapping). But when client requests CCS files server returns 406 error (and Homecontroller method didn't called):

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

Is there any chance to fix order for Spring resource handler or fix response for CSS files at all so I could manually return it from server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It causes bad mapping configuration. In your case you should use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = {"text/plain", "application/*"})
@Controller
public class HomeController {
...
}
```

insead of

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", produces = {"text/plain", "application/*"})
@Controller
public class HomeController {
...
}
```

In my case, problem appears when i wrote

```
@RequestMapping(name="/method", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(Model model){
...
}
```

instead of

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String myMethod(Model model){
...
}
```

The problem is the same in all cases - remapping all request to your method/controller so that css (js, or whatever) static files are redirected to your code.